# How to access all subclasses and strings of a JSON file in Java?

Tags: java, json, parsing, reader

I need to print info from different JSON files (that will be specified in args[0]) and print them.

All the possible access files appear as such (this is kinda a shortened version of the JSON file)

```
 {
   "DefinitionSource" : "",
   "Heading" : "Valley Forge National Historical Park",
   "RelatedTopics" : [
        "FirstURL" : //url here
        "Text" : "hello world"
 },
 {
        "FirstURL" : //url here
        "Text" : "hello world"
 },
 ]
```

there are lots of these sub classes that are different based on the JSON file that is chosen to be accessed. For the specified JSON file i need to access all the Strings in the JSON file labeled "Text". This is the bit of code that I'm using:

```
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
JsonObject mainObject = reader.readObject(); 
JSONObject RelatedTopic = json.getJSONObject("RelatedTopics");
String text = RelatedTopic.getString("Text");
System.out.println("Textual Description: " + text);
```

Comment: Not answering your question but just to let you know that using upper case for the first letter of a variable is not considered good practice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void find_text(JsonObject obj){
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()){
        String key = keys.next()
        if (key == "Text") {
            .. do your stuff ....
        } else if (obj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) 
            find_text(obj.get(key))

      }
}
```

This searches through all the keys of the JSON text and if it's an object calls the method recursively.